# Malformed HTML in exchange server calendar invite

Tags: email, outlook, calendar, jakarta-mail, exchange-server

I'm using javamail lib to send calendar invites. I notice exchange server adds this to the text/html part of the mail. The text/plain and text/calendar parts are not modified.

```
<meta name=3D"Generator" content=3D"Microsoft Exchange Server">
<!-- converted from rtf -->
<style><!-- .EmailQuote { margin-left: 1pt; padding-left: 4pt; border-left:=
#800000 2px solid; } --></style>
```

This behavior is not noticed when

- the invite is received by a non-exchange email like @gmail.com.
- when the exact text/html content is sent without the text/calendar part to an exchange email.

I believe exchange server is treating text/html in calendar invites differently, but I'm not able to find a solution that works for both exchange and non-exchange servers.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook prior to 2016 always converted HTML in the meeting requests in RTF (which is/was the native body format for the appointments / tasks / contacts).

What version of Outlook and Exchange are you using?

Comment: I'm using outlook for mac 2011. Not sure about the exchange server version.

Comment: I don't know what Outlook for Mac does, sorry.